# Module autoloader problem in zf

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have 3 moulde like blow ,

```
 application
        |
        modules
           |
           default
             |---models
             |--views
             |--forms
             |--controller-
                           |-indexController
                           |-errorController
          admin
             |---models-
                        |-user.php
             |--views
             |--forms
             |--controller--
                            |-userController
          cars
             |---models
             |--views
             |--forms
             |--controller

    bootstrap.php
```

and in my appliction.ini

i have this config

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
```

and in my bootsrap file i have this autoloader

```
$modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => '',
                    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ));
```

so i can not access to my models class in userController and other controllers

i have this code in my userController

```
$userModel = new admin_Model_Users();
```

but i got error can not find this class

and this class is in user.php

```
class admin_Model_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{


 public function getListUser() {


    }
}
```

someone may help where is my wrong and how could fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of

```
 $modelLoader = new
 Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                     'namespace' => '',
                     'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ));
```

and add 
Bootstrap.php in you module:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

also name your class Admin_Model_Users and use it accordigly where appropriorate.
Use capital "U" in the filename, capital "A" in the class name. I mean names should be consistent and in accordance to ZF guidelines.

Also in ini file: 
change entry to

```
resources.modules[] =
```

Comment: It works, it's a standard module configuration. Try to do it in an empty Zf project and maybe change some options.

Comment: try also resources.modules[] = ""

Comment: @user1400: everything greg said here is correct and should fix your problem. If you are still having issues, edit your question to include how your app is now structured just so we can see where the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`class admin_Model_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`

Should become

`class Models_UsersAdmin extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`

---

`$userModel = new admin_Model_Users();`

Should become

`$userModel = new Models_UsersAdmin();`

---

Update

in you're application.ini file where you register you're namespaces add the following line:
`autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Models"` ( or register the namespace "Models" at bootstrap )

Comment: Poelinca, that's not what namespaces are for.

Answer (score 0):

```
;define modules after controller in application.ini file
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```